# Finding the probability using Markov chain

Tags: discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

A man is at an integral point on the x-axis between the origin and the point 3. He takes a unit step to the right with probability 1/3 or to the left with probability 2/3, unless he is at the origin, where he takes a step to the right to reach the point 1 or is at the point 3, where he takes a step to the left to reach the point2. What is the probability that (i) he is at the point 1 after 3 walks? and (ii) he is at the point 1 in the long run?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to specify the transition probability matrix, which seems to be

$$P = \left[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]$$

where the columns represent states $0,1,2,3$. The second part of your question can be answered by calculating the stationary distribution of this Markov chain. The first part is ambiguous because the starting state has not been specified; however, for any given starting state, you can find all sequences of $3$ transitions that end in state $1$ and add up their probabilities. There are not many such sequences, so you can do this calculation for every possible starting state.